# Prove $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+a}>e\ \forall x>0$ when $a\geq1/2$

Tags: inequality

Prove $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+a}>e\ \forall x>0$ when $a\geq1/2$

I can't do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

prove that $\left(1+{1\over x}\right)^{x+a}$ is decreasing and $\left(1+{1\over x}\right)^{x}$ is increasing for $a\ge 0.5$ as [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vnwedy3pn3) suggests.